# Excel, specify certain cell using Name field

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I created a macro that doesn't allow values in both the B and C columns of an Excel sheet. I want to make an exception to that formula by allowing cells with the names DayShift or AfterShift.

I created this:

```
If ActiveCell.Name = "DayShift" Or ActiveCell.Name = "AfterShift" Then
```

But it doesn't seem to work and just makes other cells error. Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: You'll have to give more details than that... can you post the whole macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If ActiveCell.Name.Name = "DayShift" Or ActiveCell.Name.Name = "AfterShift" Then
```